# How to create multiple instances of the same class in as3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Noob question. Ok, so I'm trying to create two instances of my notes (it's an imported pic) class at separate x and y coordinates, then I want both of them to move right. Right now I programmed a loop, and the loop works OK, but it only keeps the last instance that was created. Here's my code. I really appreciate any help that anyone can give. Thanks!

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
private var speed:int = 8;
[Embed(source="../lib/Dodgethis.jpg")]
public var Notes:Class;

public var numnotes:Number;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, testevent);

        }

    private function testevent(e:Event = null):void {
        trace("testevent has run");
        appear(350, 250);
        //ap2(150, 150)
        //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);    
    }

    private function appear(x:Number, y:Number) {
        var arr1:Array = new Array;
        numnotes = 4;

        for (var i = 0; i < numnotes; i++)
        {
            trace (i);
            var nbm:Bitmap = new Notes;

            if (i == 0) {
                this.x = 400;
                this.y = 400;
                addChild(nbm);
                trace ("1 should be different");
            } else {
                trace ("this is working");
                this.x = 150;
                this.y = 150;
                addChild(nbm);
                arr1.push(nbm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created 4 Notes, but their positions are same point (0,0).

Comment: So how would I go about changing the position of each Note individually?

Comment: When you add nbm to the parent, just set nbm's x and y. like nbm.x = 50*i. What I understand about  moving them to the right, is set the notes's x to the same value but keep their y.